# Enlightenment E20: how to remove desktop gadget?

Tags: x11, enlightenment

I try E20 DE.

Mouse click on desktop calls the menu -> Main -> Desktop -> + Add Gadgets To Desktop.

Then I click on Thermal gadget and click on desktop.

The problem is that I can't remove it from the desktop. I can't do anything with this gadget.

By the way, there is another one option to add a gadgets on a desktop: Main -> Desktop -> Change Gadgets. These gadgets may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Left click on desktop then menu->desktop->add gadgets
then press backspace or delete to remove all the gadgets from desktop 
Even I was struggling with it when i realized it was written right there